# How to change the fontsize of indexname without affecting the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize

The following document uses a different font for the indexname, unfortunately it affects the table of contents as well.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\renewcommand*{\indexname}{\Huge my index name}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\theindex{\indexname}{\makebox[1.0\linewidth]{\indexname}}{}{}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\index{hello}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}


\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\indexname` is also used in the running heads, so changing it directly to include the font is not a good idea. Instead, use a package to update the font changes to your index chapter, like [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{makeidx,sectsty}

\makeindex
\renewcommand*{\indexname}{my index name}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\index{hello}

\cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
\chapterfont{\Huge\bfseries}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately for other reasons, I also use `\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{.26\textheight}{40pt}` in my document and this solution does not work with this. Can I ask a new question with using this or I modify this question?

Comment: @Name: That's why you should include all the details necessary as part of your question. [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) is most certainly important when you're talking about sectional titles! My solution uses [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) which is not truly compatible with `titlesec`. I'll update my answer...

Comment: Yes you are right, I tried to provide a minimal working document that reproduces the problem, but it turned out that the document was too minimal.

Comment: @Name: Just add an updated `\titleformat` immediately before `\printindex`. This will overwrite the former definition. By updated I mean you can change `\normalfont\Huge\bfseries` into whatever you need.